# Retrieving all the ancestors of a document using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The main point of this question is to know **how to properly retrieve all the ancestors of a document using Mongoose.** I'm using [this Model Tree Structures with an Array of Ancestors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/):

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "MongoDB", ancestors: [ "Books", "Programming", "Databases" ], parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "dbm", ancestors: [ "Books", "Programming", "Databases" ], parent: "Databases" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Databases", ancestors: [ "Books", "Programming" ], parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Languages", ancestors: [ "Books", "Programming" ], parent: "Programming" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Programming", ancestors: [ "Books" ], parent: "Books" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "Books", ancestors: [ ], parent: null } )
```

Here's what I'm doing, I'm trying to loop through `nextParent` and assign the result `parentCategory.parent` into it after calling `ancestors.unshift(nextParent)`, but unfortunately it doesn't work as intended as `parentCategory.parent` isn't assigning because `model.findOne()` is async:

```
const { parent } = req.body;
...
const ancestors = [];
let nextParent = parent;

while (nextParent) {
  model.findOne(
    { _id: nextParent },
    (err, parentCategory) => {
      assert.ifError(err);

      if (parentCategory) {
        ancestors.unshift(nextParent);
      }
      nextParent = parentCategory ? parentCategory.parent : false;
    }
  );
}
```

**Is there a proper way to retrieve all the ancestors of a document?** If I'm doing great, I already did this modification:

```
const ancestors = [];
let nextParent = parent;

while (nextParent) {
  let parentCategory = await model.findOne( { _id: nextParent } );

  if (parentCategory) {
    ancestors.unshift(nextParent);
  }
  nextParent = parentCategory ? parentCategory.parent : false;
}
```

I'm now getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` -> `let parentCategory = await **model.findOne(...)**`. Any solution for this?

Comment: This is a question from a MongoDB University course. Absolutely certain you are not meant to be "crowd-sourcing" the answer here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm finding a solution.